# Old Chrome plugin manifest: Unrecognized manifest key 'plugins'

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, chrome-plugins

I've got a Chrome plugin that I would like to use on current Chrome version but unfortunately upon installing, I get the following error:

> Unrecognized manifest key 'plugins'.

The manifest sort-of looks like

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    { "path": "myLib.dll", "public": true }
  ]  
}
```

I am assuming that something changed in the way that Chrome plugins are built or what is allowed and what isn't. How can I translate calling a `*.dll` file from the old format using `plugins` as a key in the manifest to the new, correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use NPAPI plugins anymore. You have to replace it with JavaScript or WebAssembly.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi:

> In September 2014, all existing NPAPI-based Apps and Extensions will be unpublished

https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation:

> In September 2015 (Chrome 45) … NPAPI support will be permanently removed from Chrome. Installed extensions that require NPAPI plugins will no longer be able to load those plugins.

Comment: This would require an alternative approach and the DLL files cannot be reused, right? So I'd need to find the source files of the DLLs? I am no C developer so I am unsure where to start and how to execute executables from within a plugin.